# Not able to extract "value" attribute from +/- box DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-tag-manager

I want to extract the "value" attribute from the selection box which allows users to select the number of quantities of an particular item on my website.

I am a newbie to both Javascript and HTML. When I do an "Inspect Element" I can see the attribute in the element

```
<input size="2" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="cart_quantity_input form-control grey" value="2" name="quantity_8329349_28095_0_12035">
```

But when I try to do either of the following two, Google Tag Manager says the variable is `undefined`

```
document.querySelectorAll("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey").value
```

OR

```
document.querySelectorAll("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey").getAttribute("value")
```

The order transaction URL is [www.decathlon.in/order](http://www.decathlon.in/order)

Comment: You can use GTMs DOM type variable, which a) will return the first match if there are multiple matches and b) means you do have to write your own JS (which is kind of the point with GTM).  You can configure it to return the value of a given attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of nodes. You need to either:

- retrieve the relevant element by index from the list:

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey")[0].value
  ```
- use `querySelector` to select only a single element:

  ```
  document.querySelector("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey").value
  ```

Comment: I just did the first one (hit and trial) before seeing this answer. But the second one seems more effective.

Thanks Rory!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GTM, why not use it for what it was intended for (which is to relieve you somewhat from coding)? Here's a solution that requires no code and uses GTM's built-in DOM variable:

[image: GTM DOM Variable]

You can set it to return the `value` attribute based on the CSS selector for the `input` element.